# cs50 filter-less blur function: blur correctly filters 3x3?

Tags: c, cs50

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int red_sum = 0;
            int green_sum = 0;
            int blue_sum = 0;
            float pixel_counter = 0; // This variable will count how many pixels we've added
            // Checking the Top row, Middle row and Bottom row
            for (int k = i - 1; k < i + 2; k++)
            {
                // Avoding segmentation fault (core dumped)
                // And checking corner case
                if (k < 0)
                {
                    k = 0;

                }

                if (k > height)
                {
                    break;
                }


                for (int l = j - 1; l < j + 2; l++)
                {
                    if (l < 0)
                    {
                        l = 0;
                    }

                    if (l > width)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    red_sum += copy[k][l].rgbtRed;
                    green_sum += copy[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                    blue_sum += copy[k][l].rgbtBlue;

                    pixel_counter += 1;
                }
            }

            int average_red = round(red_sum / pixel_counter);
            int average_green = round(green_sum / pixel_counter);
            int average_blue = round(blue_sum / pixel_counter);

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = average_red;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average_green;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average_blue;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

This is a function that should blur images. My code is almost correct. I passed all check50 tests except for: blur correctly filters 3x3 and blur correctly filters 4x4 images.

This function blurs images by passing through each pixel and averaging the RGB values of the adjacent pixels.

[image: check50 test case results]

I don't understand why my code is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Please describe what the code is doing  and what the expected input and output.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The code blurs an image. But for some reason my code is not blurring 3x3 and 4x4 images. This is cs50 problem set 4 filter-less problem.

Comment: Off-by-one error? You protect against `if (k > height)` but for `k==height` accessing `copy[k][l]` is still out-of-bounds.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  You want to edit your question to address comments.  What would be way more useful than the emojis is hard-coding a failing test case in `main()` showing us which arguments you call your function with what output you got and what you expected.